# What is the maximum size of a 802.11s wireless network?

Tags: wireless-networking, 802.11

How many nodes is it theoretically, and practically, possible to have in an 802.11s network?

Comment: Either this is documented in the standard and you can read it there, or there isn't a theoretical limit. Individual implementations may have limits, and there will be a throughput loss with each additional hop in any given transit, producing a practical limit, but, once again, this will depend on the implementation.

Answer (score 0):

The [article](https://www.nttdocomo.co.jp/english/binary/pdf/corporate/technology/rd/technical_journal/bn/vol8_2/vol8_2_013en.pdf) indicates "The IEEE 802.11s standard envisions a small- to medium- scale WLAN mesh network configured with a maximum of 32 MPs (MAPs included). Practically, each MAP can be connected to many STAs enabling the entire network to accommodate sev- eral hundred terminals."

Or do you mean the MTU?
[image]

Comment: Thanks.  I don't mean the MTU, but rather the number of nodes (i.e. entities/actors).